# Will I incur excessive costs doing something like the following with firebase keys?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime DB for my iOS app. Something I do very often is store some info in a nodes key for easy access, and to solve some other problems in my code. But I have been wondering if I will be charged more for doing something like that, instead of just storing the data inside the node.

For example I do the following (store the postID And UID in the key):

```
Timeline/uid/someUID:postID/ Other data here...
```

**Would I be causing myself to pay extra? Would it be cheaper to just use a randomID? Are there any other considerations?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, [look here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) the limit the number of conections and the amount of data stored, since id is string randomly generated if you set another id is not a diference sinc is string and would not make a huge diference, and about other data added unless is to much data a string is not make you cost extra, in free plan only 100 conections allow simultaneosly and 10GB per month of donwloaded data, and 1gb of DB, unles every node and have a lot node then there is not difference

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for now, I will consider your answer as the base.